# CSS div shifts when its height reaches the screen resolution

Tags: css

I don't know why but when the height of the content_second_box is set higher then the height of the screen resolution then the whole page shifts left by a few pixels. Once the div reaches the bottom of the screen it shifts, when the height does not reach then it is ok.
I have tried many things but nothing has worked. Does anyone please know why?

CSS is as follows:

```
body {
background-color: white;
}

#container { 

        position: relative;

        width: 1300px;

        margin-left: auto;

        margin-right: auto;

        padding: 10px 50x 30px 50px; 

}

#content { 

        width: 1000px;

        margin-left: auto;

        margin-right: auto;

        padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;

        /*text-align: center;*/

}

#content_first_box {

        width: 225px;
        height: 50px; 
     /* min-height: 160px; */
    /*  height: auto !important; */ 

        background-color: #ff8b00; /*#9caad6;*/
        border-radius:5px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 15px;

}

#content_second_box {

        width: 225px;
        height: 500px; 
     /* min-height: 160px; */
    /*  height: auto !important; */ 

        background-color: #79bbff; /*#9caad6;*/
        border-radius:5px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 15px;

}


HTML file is as follows:

    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="content_first_box">text</div>  
      <div id="content_first_box">text</div>
      <div id="content_first_box">text</div>
      <div id="content_first_box">text</div>

      <div id="content_second_box">text druhy</div>
      <div id="content_second_box">text druhy</div>
      <div id="content_second_box">text druhy</div>
      <div id="content_second_box">text druhy</div>
    </div> 
    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Does the scroll appear? that takes about 10-30px depending on browser

Comment: Why are you using similar `ids`??

Answer (score 2):

The scroll bar appears once the page is longer than the viewport. This causes all content to shift left to allow for the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the content shift by always showing the scrollbar in browser as -

```
html{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: That's gonna be the issue :-) thanx for explanation.